# First-chance exception at 0x749a4b32 in appname.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: int at memory location 0x009ad9ec vb.net

Tags: vb.net, memory

My application crashes randomly , any where , and i don't know why ! I tried to remove all thirdparty references (such as crystal reports).

the error is always about memory , "Write to protected memory"

finaly , i saw in the immediate window , there are these lines , they appear on application startup (not at application startup event) :

```
First-chance exception at 0x749a4b32 in Al-Baraka Enjaz Omra.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: int at memory location 0x009ad9ec.
First-chance exception at 0x749a4b32 in Al-Baraka Enjaz Omra.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: int at memory location 0x009ad9ec.
First-chance exception at 0x749a4b32 in Al-Baraka Enjaz Omra.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: int at memory location 0x009ae2b0.
First-chance exception at 0x749a4b32 in Al-Baraka Enjaz Omra.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: int at memory location 0x009ae2b0.
First-chance exception at 0x749a4b32 in Al-Baraka Enjaz Omra.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: int at memory location 0x0084da7c.
```

and more lines like those , why these errors happen ? and what about that the vb.net is managed code and can't throws any protected memory exceptions because it is managed code ??!!

i can't put my code : very big and i can't select the code causes that , that is on randomly lines .

Thank You

Comment: You haven't removed all suspect code, clearly you are still running native C++ code.  Sure, random crashes are common when that code swallows exceptions like this.  Enable unmanaged debugging and force the program to stop by ticking the Thrown checkboxes in Debug + Exceptions.

Comment: thank you , but what are you meaning native c++ code ? i'am using vb.net only with no any strange references , just .net references